# Error Installing Cake PHP

Tags: php, cakephp

I've followed the default documentation of installing cake php (I followed the first steps of installing composer as the dependency, for example) and I get the following error:

```
composer create-project --prefer-dist cakephp/app test_cake_app
Installing cakephp/app (3.4.2)
  - Installing cakephp/app (3.4.2)
    Loading from cache

Created project in test_cake_app
Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies (including require-dev)
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

  Problem 1
    - cakephp/cakephp 3.4.6 requires ext-intl * -> the requested PHP extension intl is missing from your system.
    - cakephp/cakephp 3.4.5 requires ext-intl * -> the requested PHP extension intl is missing from your system.
    - cakephp/cakephp 3.4.4 requires ext-intl * -> the requested PHP extension intl is missing from your system.
    - cakephp/cakephp 3.4.3 requires ext-intl * -> the requested PHP extension intl is missing from your system.
    - cakephp/cakephp 3.4.2 requires lib-icu >=4.8 -> the requested linked library icu has the wrong version installed or is missing from your system, make sure to have the extension providing it.
    - cakephp/cakephp 3.4.1 requires lib-icu >=4.8 -> the requested linked library icu has the wrong version installed or is missing from your system, make sure to have the extension providing it.
    - cakephp/cakephp 3.4.0 requires lib-icu >=4.8 -> the requested linked library icu has the wrong version installed or is missing from your system, make sure to have the extension providing it.
    - Installation request for cakephp/cakephp 3.4.* -> satisfiable by cakephp/cakephp[3.4.0, 3.4.1, 3.4.2, 3.4.3, 3.4.4, 3.4.5, 3.4.6].

  To enable extensions, verify that they are enabled in those .ini files:
    - /etc/php/7.0/cli/php.ini
    - /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/10-opcache.ini
    - /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/10-pdo.ini
    - /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/15-xml.ini
    - /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-calendar.ini
    - /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-ctype.ini
    - /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-dom.ini
    - /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-exif.ini
    - /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-fileinfo.ini
    - /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-ftp.ini
    - /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-gettext.ini
    - /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-iconv.ini
    - /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-json.ini
    - /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-mbstring.ini
    - /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-phar.ini
    - /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-posix.ini
    - /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-readline.ini
    - /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-shmop.ini
    - /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-simplexml.ini
    - /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-sockets.ini
    - /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-sysvmsg.ini
    - /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-sysvsem.ini
    - /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-sysvshm.ini
    - /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-tokenizer.ini
    - /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-wddx.ini
    - /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-xmlreader.ini
    - /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-xmlwriter.ini
    - /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-xsl.ini
    - /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-zip.ini
  You can also run `php --ini` inside terminal to see which files are used by PHP in CLI mode.
```

When I try to run `sudo apt-get install php53-intl`, I get the following error:

`Unable to locate package php53-intl`

Anyone know of any workarounds for this?

Comment: You should search for how to install intl first.

Comment: php53-intl <- is obviously wrong because it seems you run 7.0. It's at least looking for a 7.0 folder `/etc/php/7.0/`.

Comment: is there a php7-intl package or something?